Do we use "two" or "2" in a mathematical essay? "The number [two/2] is the only even prime" and "Graph a function of [two/2] variables"
I've heard that when doing formal writing, we normally spell out numbers under 10, but in mathematics we use digits for all numbers.
For example, we use the word "two" when writing essays but the number "2" in mathematical situations.
When doing a mathematical essay, should I use "two" or "2" in the following scenarios?

"The number [two/2] is the only even prime"
"Graph a function of [two/2] variables"


I’m voting to close this question because, as a request for recommended style within the maths domain, and not for standard (everyday) English usage (which ELU concentrates on), and which may well (and confusingly) be different,, this is better asked on Mathematics.SE. // In any case, there are probably different requirements at different institutions. Where relevant, it is always best to consult the appropriate tutor or recommended style guide.

In case it's not clear from Edwin's comment, the answer is "There's no one right way, but there's probably a style guide you should check."

The [tag:grammar] tag is misused here. Strictly speaking, “grammar” includes the twin key components of syntax and morphology, and more broadly also phonology, semantics, pragmatics, and discourse analysis. Grammar does ɴᴏᴛ include style conventions, register, politeness, nor any merely technological matters such as a language’s orthography ᴀᴋᴀ its writing (ie: alphabet & script, capitalization, spelling, hyphenation, punctuation) or its typesetting (ie: font, slant, weight, symbols, glyph variants, spacing, footnotes, super- & subscripts, colors & decorative ornaments).

Didn't someone ask this a few days ago? I believe it was closed.
